# Magento memory performance

Tags: performance, magento, memory

I have a huge problem in **Magento 1.7.0.2** when importing ~400k of products.
Due to an custom interface i created a custom product import where the products get created, upsellungs/cross-sellings get saved.

Pseudo:

```
do {
  if( $_product = Mage::getModel(catalog/product)->loadByAttribute('sku', $sku)){
     return $_product;
  }else{
     $product = $this->createProduct();
     $product->save();
  }
}while(!$end_of_import);
```

Each processed product (load/save...) needs ~180kb of memory.
The problem: the memory never gets released!
So after ~50k-60k of imported products the allowed memory size of 10gb is exhausted.

I tried different solutions as posted [here](http://blog.ewtechnologies.com/magento-2/magento-memory-leak-1-4-1-1/) or [here](http://ringsdorff.net/2009/07/23/guest-post-fix-for-memory-leaks-in-magento/) but no effect.

Answer (score 3):

How about the indexes? On the backend interface the Indexing is set to "update on save" by default. If you iterate over a lot of products and save them as you described, a reindexing process will start after each save. Try to change the mode to "Manual" (System/Index management), and execute the import afterwards.

Comment: Indexing is set to mode manual: `Mage_Index_Model_Process::MODE_MANUAL`

Comment: OK. This issue is not new in 1.7, as far as i know this problem exists  since the beginnings. The next thing i would try is to disable all event observers before/aster product save. Unfortunatelly you only can do it in the core code, which is not recommended - so could be a temporary solution.

Comment: My "solution" is now to split the import in several bulk imports ... perhaps if i'll find some time i'll debug the hell out of magento, to find a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Call $product->clearInstance() after the save, so not only the product itself is removed, but also everything else attached to it.

Comment: Has no effect to me, memory usage is still increasing.

Comment: It's always increasing a bit, but reduces the usage a lot

Comment: Could not notice an improvement. 
Bevore: 5 articles ~800kb - 
After: 5 articles ~790kb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [unset](http://php.net/unset) ? for `$_product` and `$product`?

Comment: After some code optimization, several unsets() of variables and loaded arrays and the solution mentioned in the second link it seems that this memory problem has been solved.
About 10% usage, really slowly increasing.

Comment: edit: still increasing, slowly but it does. There is still something cached/stored in ram ...